# gesture detection on ScrollView with checktextviews

Tags: android, gesture

I have setup an OnTouchListener on a ScrollView that contains a list of CheckTextView objects. If I swipe in the CTV's I get nothing. If I swipe below the CTV's I get UP and DOWN events. If I tap on the CTV's I get onClicks.

Here's what I have:

```
   View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Down:"+event);
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d(TAG, "Up:"+event);
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Click!");
        }
    };

    findViewById(R.id.scrollView).setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    findViewById(R.id.chkTxt01).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    + 6 more setOnClickListeners
```

In activity_main:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/chkTxt01"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
            android:text="@string/random_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       + 6 more CheckedTextViews

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What is requirement can you specify a bit more.

Comment: I want to get ACTION_UP ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_MOVE events from onTouch when I swipe over the CheckedTextViews inside a ScrollView.